# Spring Data Neo4j and DynamicProperties

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

In SDN 4 I can't find  [DynamicProperties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/3.0.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/fieldaccess/DynamicProperties.html). Is any alternative provided by SDN4 in order to emulate something similar to DynamicProperties that was present in SDN 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDN 4 does not support the Dynamic Properties functionality from SDN 3. 
You can still save and retrieve dynamic properties via SDN 4 if you model them in something like a Map, and then write a [custom converter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference_programming-model_conversion-custom) to persist/retrieve them as a String(maybe JSON is a good representation here)